# Upload a file into SharePoint using FORM POST

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, http-post

I would like to upload a file into share point using FORM POST. I am trying in this way

```
<FORM NAME="oForm" id="oForm"  ACTION="<site>/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={A4793E2B-3081-4668-B6F1-0A013159F9B1}&RootFolder=/sites/servdeldocmgr/Test SOAP2"    ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"    METHOD="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file1"  id="file1" />
</FORM>
```

In onclick of a button I am doing form post. But It's not uploading. I found .net based solutions but my case is only with javascript and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to add attachment to list item. I put my experience here. Instead of uploading to upload.aspx, I achieved differently. I am able to achieve without .net, I found many .net solutions but again it will be one more programming language in application stack so I didn't use it.

http://myveda-yvb.blogspot.com/2010/01/my-learnings-sharepoint-web-services.html

Answer (score 2):

The best is to rely on SharePoint API, populate the item (e.g SPList) and upload the file. I will provide some sample code later as I can't recall the exact function.

EDIT:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587349(office.11).aspx has some good code snippets to get you started.